# Documentation generated by Yard and spanish accents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, yard

I'm generating documentation with Yard, and all my comments have been written in Spanish. The problem is that the documentation generated by Yard contains � instead of Spanish accents.

I've used "yardoc" command.
I'm using ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32] and Rails 3.0.7
Running on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Probably your source files are encoded in ISO Latin 1 while Yard expects them to be in UTF-8.

You could instruct Yard to read your files in ISO Latin 1 instead of the default UTF-8, but I strongly suggest you to re-encode your source files as UTF-8 files. Any decent text editor should be able to do that with one or two clicks.

Comment: I have in my application.rb
`config.encoding = "utf-8"` so I expect all my source files encoded in UTF-8. 
I've tried the command

Comment: Sorry, once again
I have in my application.rb
`config.encoding = "utf-8"` 
so I expect all my source files encoded in UTF-8. 
I've tried the command `yardoc --charset ISO-8859`
 but the generated html files have in the header
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
I don't know if I've understood what you are saying. Do you mean delete the spanish accents from my comments so I have all my source files in uTF-8?

Comment: `config.encoding = "utf-8"` is not related to the encoding used to save the source files. You do not need to remove those accents, that is a bit too much :). Just tell your editor (which editor is that, btw?) to save again your files in UTF-8. That will make the diamond characters disappear.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with Aptana plugin
I've change from Cp1252 to UTF8 (you were rigth, all source files were saved in Cp1252 by Eclipse) but when a run yardoc command, the html file still have the encoding to UTF8, which is the expected encoding because is the Yard encoding by default, and the diamonds still appear on the documentation. I've also tried changing the encoding in Eclipse to ISO but the result is the same.

Thank you very much btw